# React-Router-DOM does not work with nested paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a simple AppContainer component, where I'm using:

```
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8"
```

packages to navigate throw whole app. But for some reasons, it does not work in the case when I'm trying to go to a deeper location that `/` base location. And for now, I always get an error on any of `location_1/2/3/4` paths... Error message:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash

My AppComponent structure:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'


export const AppContainer = ({ store, history }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <CoreLayout children={<Hub />} /> }/>
          <Route path="/location_1" render={() => <Component_Holder.component {...store} children={<Component_1 {...store} />} /> }/>
          <Route path="/location_2" render={() => <Component_2 {...store} /> }/>
          <Route path="/location_3" render={() => <Component_3 {...store} /> }/>
          <Route path="/location_4" render={() => <Component_4 {...store} /> }/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

P.S.
I what to admit, that my base path `/` works normally.

I'll grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `<HashRouter>`, instead of `<BrowserRouter>` to serve your app `Routing`. I think this is the main problem in you case, which happen when you need to serve the old-fashion `hash` routing, like: `app.com/#/some_nested_route_page`.

And also because the solution of @Ricardo Costa should have worked...

So, take this and try again:

```
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

export const AppContainer = ({ store, history }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store} history={history}>
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <CoreLayout children={<Hub />} /> }/>
          <Route path="/location_1" render={() => <Component_Holder.component {...store} children={<Component_1 {...store} />} /> }/>
          <Route path="/location_2" render={() => <Component_2 {...store} /> }/>
          <Route path="/location_3" render={() => <Component_3 {...store} /> }/>
          <Route path="/location_4" render={() => <Component_4 {...store} /> }/>
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right! I'm already forgot about this question and solve it by myself in such way!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      <Route
        path={yourPath}
        component={store => (
          <Component_2 {...store} title={'Dashboard'} />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: The same result . (